# How do I partially sort a Vec or slice?

Tags: performance, sorting, vector, rust, partial-sort

I need to get the top N items from a `Vec` which is quite large in production. Currently I do it like this inefficient way:

```
let mut v = vec![6, 4, 3, 7, 2, 1, 5];
v.sort_unstable();
v = v[0..3].to_vec();
```

In C++, I'd use [`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort), but I can't find an equivalent in the [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).

Am I just overlooking it, or does it not exist (yet)?

Comment: The standard library does not offer such functionality. Maybe a [crate](https://crates.io/search?q=partial%20sort) can solve your problem or [BinaryHeap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html) which is always sorted?

Comment: Using `BinaryHeap` from the standard library, it is pretty easy to implement this yourself. Basically, if you want to find the `k` smallest values from your vector, start by creating a heap from the first `k` values in your vector. Then iterate over the rest of the vector, and in each step add the current element to the heap and then remove the greatest element from the heap using `pop()`. Once you reached the end of the heap, use the `into_sorted_vec()` method to get the `k` smallest elements in sorted order.

Comment: @hellow I wouldn't call a binary heap "always sorted".

Comment: You could also keep track of the N biggest elements while populating the vector; it should be pretty simple as long as the populating code is contained in a single spot. You could also consider crafting a custom object containing the vector and a list of N biggest elements that automatically updates that list when it's populated (using a custom method).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard library doesn't contain this functionality, but it looks like the [`lazysort`](https://crates.io/crates/lazysort) crate is exactly what you need:

> So what's the point of lazy sorting? As per the linked blog post, they're useful when you do not need or intend to need every value; for example you may only need the first 1,000 ordered values from a larger set.

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate lazysort;
extern crate rand;
extern crate test;

use std::cmp::Ordering;

trait SortLazy<T> {
    fn sort_lazy<F>(&mut self, cmp: F, n: usize)
    where
        F: Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering;
    unsafe fn sort_lazy_fast<F>(&mut self, cmp: F, n: usize)
    where
        F: Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering;
}

impl<T> SortLazy<T> for [T] {
    fn sort_lazy<F>(&mut self, cmp: F, n: usize)
    where
        F: Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering,
    {
        fn sort_lazy<F, T>(data: &mut [T], accu: &mut usize, cmp: &F, n: usize)
        where
            F: Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering,
        {
            if !data.is_empty() && *accu < n {
                let mut pivot = 1;
                let mut lower = 0;
                let mut upper = data.len();
                while pivot < upper {
                    match cmp(&data[pivot], &data[lower]) {
                        Ordering::Less => {
                            data.swap(pivot, lower);
                            lower += 1;
                            pivot += 1;
                        }
                        Ordering::Greater => {
                            upper -= 1;
                            data.swap(pivot, upper);
                        }
                        Ordering::Equal => pivot += 1,
                    }
                }
                sort_lazy(&mut data[..lower], accu, cmp, n);
                sort_lazy(&mut data[upper..], accu, cmp, n);
            } else {
                *accu += 1;
            }
        }
        sort_lazy(self, &mut 0, &cmp, n);
    }

    unsafe fn sort_lazy_fast<F>(&mut self, cmp: F, n: usize)
    where
        F: Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering,
    {
        fn sort_lazy<F, T>(data: &mut [T], accu: &mut usize, cmp: &F, n: usize)
        where
            F: Fn(&T, &T) -> Ordering,
        {
            if !data.is_empty() && *accu < n {
                unsafe {
                    use std::mem::swap;
                    let mut pivot = 1;
                    let mut lower = 0;
                    let mut upper = data.len();
                    while pivot < upper {
                        match cmp(data.get_unchecked(pivot), data.get_unchecked(lower)) {
                            Ordering::Less => {
                                swap(
                                    &mut *(data.get_unchecked_mut(pivot) as *mut T),
                                    &mut *(data.get_unchecked_mut(lower) as *mut T),
                                );
                                lower += 1;
                                pivot += 1;
                            }
                            Ordering::Greater => {
                                upper -= 1;
                                swap(
                                    &mut *(data.get_unchecked_mut(pivot) as *mut T),
                                    &mut *(data.get_unchecked_mut(upper) as *mut T),
                                );
                            }
                            Ordering::Equal => pivot += 1,
                        }
                    }
                    sort_lazy(&mut data[..lower], accu, cmp, n);
                    sort_lazy(&mut data[upper..], accu, cmp, n);
                }
            } else {
                *accu += 1;
            }
        }
        sort_lazy(self, &mut 0, &cmp, n);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use test::Bencher;

    use lazysort::Sorted;
    use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
    use SortLazy;

    use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

    const SIZE_VEC: usize = 100_000;
    const N: usize = 42;

    #[bench]
    fn sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = std::iter::repeat_with(|| rng.gen())
                .take(SIZE_VEC)
                .collect();
            v.sort_unstable();
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn lazysort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = thread_rng();
            let v: Vec<i32> = std::iter::repeat_with(|| rng.gen())
                .take(SIZE_VEC)
                .collect();
            let _: Vec<_> = v.iter().sorted().take(N).collect();
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn lazysort_in_place(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = std::iter::repeat_with(|| rng.gen())
                .take(SIZE_VEC)
                .collect();
            v.sort_lazy(i32::cmp, N);
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn lazysort_in_place_fast(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = std::iter::repeat_with(|| rng.gen())
                .take(SIZE_VEC)
                .collect();
            unsafe { v.sort_lazy_fast(i32::cmp, N) };
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn binaryheap(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = thread_rng();
            let v: Vec<i32> = std::iter::repeat_with(|| rng.gen())
                .take(SIZE_VEC)
                .collect();

            let mut iter = v.iter();
            let mut heap: BinaryHeap<_> = iter.by_ref().take(N).collect();
            for i in iter {
                heap.push(i);
                heap.pop();
            }
            let _ = heap.into_sorted_vec();
        })
    }
}
```

```
running 5 tests
test tests::binaryheap             ... bench:   3,283,938 ns/iter (+/- 413,805)
test tests::lazysort               ... bench:   1,669,229 ns/iter (+/- 505,528)
test tests::lazysort_in_place      ... bench:   1,781,007 ns/iter (+/- 443,472)
test tests::lazysort_in_place_fast ... bench:   1,652,103 ns/iter (+/- 691,847)
test tests::sort                   ... bench:   5,600,513 ns/iter (+/- 711,927)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 5 measured; 0 filtered out
```

This code allows us to see that `lazysort` is faster than the solution with `BinaryHeap`. We can also see that `BinaryHeap` solution gets worse when `N` increases.

The problem with `lazysort` is that it creates a second `Vec<_>`. A "better" solution would be to implement the partial sort in-place. I provided an example of such an implementation.

Keep in mind that all these solutions come with overhead. When `N` is about `SIZE_VEC / 3`, the classic `sort` wins.

You could submit an RFC/issue to ask about adding this feature to the standard library.

Comment: It looks like the crate might actually have the partially-sorted vector internally; I wonder if it would be "trivial" to expose that directly.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, it is trivial but lazysort use a stack to save its state, it's not necessary when you don't use an iterator.

Answer (score 8):

There is a [`select_nth_unstable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.select_nth_unstable), the equivalent of `std::nth_element`. The result of this can then be sorted to achieve what you want.

Example:

```
let mut v = vec![6, 4, 3, 7, 2, 1, 5];
let top_three = v.select_nth_unstable(3).0;
top_three.sort();
```

`3` here is the index of the "nth" element, so we're actually picking the 4th element, that's because `select_nth_unstable` returns a tuple of

- a slice to the left of the nth element
- a reference to the nth element
- a slice to the right of the nth element

Comment: `select_nth_unstable()` is already unstable, so there is no point in using stable `sort()`. Use `sort_unstable()`.